# How to prevent users who are not logged in from accessing the admin route?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

In my application the users don't have accounts, so by default every registered account is an admin account. When an admin logs in, he receives a valid token with which he can make POST request to the back-end and create/update/delete content.

Here's my problem - even though non-admins can't create/read/update/delete content through the admin panel because they don't have a valid token and the back-end rejects their POST requests, they can still visit the admin panel by navigating to `/admin`.

I can check if the user is logged in by checking if the Vuex user object is empty or not, and redirect the user to home if he's not logged in, but I'm pretty if the user desires it, he can spoof being logged in ( the token would still be invalid ).

What is the best course of action here?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is use [vue-session-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-session) and make a session after admin is logged in successfully. Then you can check if session is present or not . If present give permission to use /admin router or redirect the user to login page. To know more browse session and cookies uses.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a global before on your router which will be executed on every call to you can check the user permission.

Details:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    // ...
})
```

To create a more structured way, you can add meta data on your ***router.js***

> You can add the user ROLE to your TOKEN

```
{
    path: '/admin/path',
    meta: { requiresAuth: true, roles:[ADMIN, MANAGER] }
}
```

> ADMIN, MANAGER can be Strings, Number, it's up to your logic.

So the *beforeEach* would be like:

```
router.beforeEach((to,from,next) => {
    //get the authenticated user 
    const authUser = store.getters.getUser
    //check sensitive routes
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
        if (!authUser) {
            next('/login')
        } else {
            //check user ROLE/Permission
            if (hasPermission(authUser, to.meta.roles)) {
                next()
            } else {
                next('/unauthorized')
            }
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
})
```

The *hasPermission* function only checks if the authenticated user has a ROLE which allows him to access the Path.